# Is it possible to symlink a ssh command?

Tags: bash, ssh, symbolic-link

I am pretty new to linux/bash, and I have just recently learned about symlinks. I spend a lot of time at work logging on to various web servers using ssh and our server provider has some horrible long domains. Is it possible to use symlinks in a manner that will allow me to simply type a single designation to ssh to the server?

example:

```
ln -s ssh customer@host customer
```

then use 'customer' as a single command to run the ssh command ?

Comment: Symlinks are for files - so you'll need to create a script with that command in it and the symlink it (or not). You're looking for the wrong thing here, use SSH configuration + bash aliases or functions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an alias. An alias is made like this:
`alias somecommand="someotherverylongcommandwithaverylongcommandname thearguments"`
Then, you can run somecommand and it will run the other command. To make it permanent, however, you need to edit your ~/.bash_aliases file. Open it in your prefered text editor and put in the alias command. Then, the alias will be set on bash startup.
Note: You may need to create the ~/.bash_aliases file. Also, ~ is the /home/*username* folder. Also, the . at the beginning means that the file is hidden.

Comment: I would recommend to combine this with a ~.ssh/config configuration. so using an alias is only for a short naming, but using a custom-ssh config can shorten calling special connection configurations.

Comment: @lkj I didn't know about that file, but I chose to explain aliases as they are more variable. (You can use them with any command, not only with ssh) Thanks for the tip, though!